# Android Array to Javascript Array how

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, socket.io

Array Javascript

```
var game = {
  turn : 'X',
  score : { X: 0, O: 0 },
  moves : 0,
  tiles : {
  1: '',
  2: '',
  4: '',
  8: '',
  16: '',
  32: '',
  64: '',
  128: '',
  256: ''
  },
  wins : [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84],
  players : [],
  id: room
};
```

I am trying to do an application with Socket.io. I need to send data like the array above the server how do I do it?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(game)`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(game)` is correct. Just wanted to note that `game` is an object, not an array.